# how to pass string path in subprocess command line?

Tags: python, format, subprocess

So i have a code where i use the subprocess.popen method, i want to pass a string path on settings but i dont know how to do it.

there is my code :

```
screenCommand = rep_reference+"\osgedit\osgviewer.exe "

iterationsPath = str(path + "\sreplace.osg")
        command = "{0} --screen 0 --window 0 0 1920 1080 path+\sreplace.osg {1} " .format(screenCommand, listFix[e])

        process = subprocess.Popen(command)

        time.sleep(3.0)

        process.kill()
```

how to path the iterationsPath variable on my command settings ?

Answer (score 0):

You pass the various arguments and options in a list along with the command.

For example, to open VSCode in the current directory, in the shell you would do:

```sh
$ code .
```

Using `subprocess.Popen()` (or `subprocess.call()`):

```py
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen(['code', '.'])
>>>
```

Essentially you split the shell command by spaces.

From the docs

> On POSIX, if args is a string, the string is interpreted as the name
>   or path of the program to execute. However, this can only be done if
>   not passing arguments to the program.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Comment: @skehal I have no idea what you mean by 'my format'. You can't pass a string as you would type it in the shell, if that is what you mean. That is not how it works. I've edited the answer to include an excerpt from the docs and a link to relevant section.